# Add JSON files from ruby script to MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a problem for save Json files from my ruby script.
i tried all solutions but nothing work.
i started from:

```
require "mongo"
client = mongo::Client.new(['27017'])
database = Mongo::Database.new(client,'database')
collection = Mongo::Collection.new(database,'ID')
collection.create
```

and when i try to store JSON in mongo i launch:

```
collection = Mongo::Collection.insert() or
client[:ID].insert_one(my_json_files) or
collection.insert(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(my_json_files))
```

i tried all these solutions.